# Java null pointer exception, when using JButton

Tags: java, swing

```
code 1:
String s = Character.toString(button[0]);
bt[0].setText(s);//bt[]: JButton array;, button[] = char array
code 2:
String s = Character.toString(button[0]);
bt[0] = new JButton(s);
```

Suppose, I already initialize bt's by new JButton[num];
code 1 leads to null pointer exception, but code 2 run well.
I think bt's already has a pointer value of null. then, i can modify them without restriction. but it isn't.
I think code 2 initialize 2 times. but, it hasn't to be.

Comment: When you create an array of reference types (such as `JButton[] bt = new JButton[100]`). You allocate space to store one hundred `JButton` instances, but they are all `null`. Your second example invokes the `JButton` constructor to actually instantiate a `JButton`.

Comment: is there any difference with them?...  if we allocate memory for some variables, then aren't we can freely use those position?..

Comment: *is there any difference with them?* **Yes**. One works. The other doesn't. If you were to fill the array with `JButton`(s) then code 1 would work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you initialized bt with new JButton[num];. But its content is still null, so bt[0] is null... So you try to run the method setText on a null reference.

Comment: so that is the problem. But, i'm not dereferencing null. still is it problem?..

Comment: Yes, it is. When you create the array you're telling Java you will create a bunch of those objects, but none of them are actually created. Thus referencing any if those positions will be a null pointer. You should assign those pointer to real objects, just like you are in the code 2

Comment: thanks. null pointer can't dereference.